# Looping Through A List, Create New Worksheets Based on that List

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I am currently doing a project. I have a list of job titles on Column A on a sheet named "Master". I need to loop through that list and check if they exist as worksheets. If they don't, it should create a worksheet with what's on the list. I was able to do this part however:

I have another sheet named "Data". This contains the data of employees like their full name, date of hire, their job title, and contact number. I need to segregate them by their job title and paste them on their respective worksheets that were created through the list on the sheet named "Master".

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub CreateSheetsFromAList()
Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range
Dim ans As Long

Sheet4.Select
Range("M2").Select
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select
Set MyRange = Selection
For Each MyCell In MyRange
    If Len(MyCell.Text) > 0 Then
        'Check if sheet exists
        If Not SheetExists(MyCell.Value) Then
            Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
            Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet
            'Worksheets("Master").Cells.Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

            'run report codes here

            Sheet3.Select
            Range("A:T").AutoFilter
            Range("D1").Select
            Range("D1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=MyCell.Value, Operator:=xlFilterValues

            Range("A1:T1").Select
            Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Range("A1:T" & Lastrow).Select
            Selection.Copy

            Range("AH2").Select
            ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        Else

            'insert code for updating of reports here
        End If
    End If

Next MyCell
End Sub

Function SheetExists(shtName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean
Dim sht As Worksheet

 If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
 On Error Resume Next
 Set sht = wb.Sheets(shtName)
 On Error GoTo 0
 SheetExists = Not sht Is Nothing
 End Function
```

For example:
I need to filter the data by job title.. So for example, my loop created a worksheet named Waiters. The Data sheet will be filtered and all the employees whose job title is waiter will be copied to the sheet Waiters. After that, it will continue to loop through my list on the sheet Master and create another worksheet, for example Cooks. And then again the Data sheet will be filtered and all the employees whose job title is cook will be copied to the sheet Cooks. It will continue to loop until the last entry on my list on Master sheet.

Please help

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Side note: you want to [avoid using select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) in your code.

Comment: So where are you stuck specifically. It looks like you have a decent start. Are you asking how to create a new workbook? FYI a bit of terminology but `workbook` refers to the excel file as a hole, `worksheet` refers to the tabs within that workbook. I just want to be sure what you are asking

Comment: I need to segregate each employee's data that are on the sheet named Data and put them on their respective worksheets while the worksheets are being created by the loop. Sorry I'm finding it hard to explain because I am also not sure if that is possible

Comment: So where are you stuck? Although the Select methods are not ideal, it appears your code should function enough to loop through your data. Which part of the code specifically are you struggling with?

Comment: For example, the loop created a worksheet named Cashiers. Before it will create the next worksheet, it should get all the employees' data from the Data sheet whose job title is Cashier and paste it on the Cashiers sheet. After that it will continue to create the next sheet based on the list on Master sheet.

Comment: @EricF I am stuck on the loop where there is a comment saying 'put codes here for segregating employees by job title and put on their respective worksheets

Comment: So your question is `how do I copy data from existing data into my newly created workbook`?

Comment: @EricF yes. So the code has to copy the data from existing into the newly created worksheet not workbook. My code above creates new worksheets in the same workbook

Comment: So you can reference current worksheet data like this: `Thisworkbook.Sheets("worksheet_name").Range("A2").value` and the new workbook's data the same way. So for example if I want A3 on my new sheet equal to A2 on my old sheet I would simply put `Thisworkbook.sheets("new_worksheet_name").Range("A3").value = Thisworkbook.sheets("old_worksheet_name").Range("A2").value`. Make sense?

Comment: I need to filter the data by job title.. So for example, my loop created a worksheet named Waiters. The Data sheet will be filtered and all the employees whose job title is waiter will be copied to the sheet Waiters. After that, it will continue to loop through my list on the sheet Master and create another worksheet, for example Cooks. And then again the Data sheet will be filtered and all the employees whose job title is cook will be copied to the sheet Cooks. It will continue to loop until the last entry on my list on Master sheet. Sorry does it make sense?

Comment: Yep. Will you want the data removed from the original Master sheet after it is added to the new sheets?

Comment: No, the raw data has to stay where they are. I just need them copied

Comment: I added an answer that should contain everything you need based on the information you provided

Answer (score 0):

**Example Workbook**

So I have created a Workbook similar to yours, but not exact:

[image]

[image]

The key features of the table are:

- The Job Title column: This is what the worksheet names are based on.
- A column to indicate if the data has been copied over already or not since you said you don't want the rows removed from the `Master` sheet.
- The rest of the data can be anything. I just filled mine out with garbage data.

**My Macro**

```
Public Sub copy_new_people()

Dim job_name As String

Dim insert_index As Integer
Dim employee As String
Dim employee_index As Integer


For Row = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Range("D" & Row).Value <> "y" Then 'don't re-copy items
        'does worksheet exist?
        job_name = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Range("A" & Row).Value
        If WorksheetExists(job_name, ThisWorkbook) = False Then
            'create worksheet
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = job_name
            'add headers
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(job_name).Range("A1").Value = "Job Title"
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(job_name).Range("B1").Value = "Header1"
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(job_name).Range("C1").Value = "Header2"
        End If

        'now add data
        'get next available index
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(job_name).Range("A2").Value = "" Then
            insert_index = 2
        Else
            insert_index = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(job_name).Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row + 1
        End If


        'get employee index for employee data
        employee = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Range("B" & Row).Value

        For row2 = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
            If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A" & row2).Value = employee Then
                employee_index = row2
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(job_name).Range("A" & insert_index).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Range("A" & Row).Value
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(job_name).Range("B" & insert_index).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("B" & employee_index).Value
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(job_name).Range("C" & insert_index).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Range("C" & employee_index).Value


        'lastly mark on Master sheet that it has been copied
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(job_name).Range("D" & insert_index).Value = "y"

    End If
Next


End Sub


Function WorksheetExists(shtName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sht = wb.Sheets(shtName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    WorksheetExists = Not sht Is Nothing
End Function
```

**Key Notes to code**

- I wrote a separate function to return true / false if the workbook contains the given worksheet by name. This makes it much more reusable and cleaner code.
- The main loop just starts from the top of the `Master` worksheet and goes to the bottom. It only looks at those rows where the `Copied` column is blank (not added yet)
- If the worksheet doesn't exist already then it creates it.
- Once the code reaches the `add data` portion, any the worksheet must already exist since it was either just created, or found before.
- `insert_index` is used to lookup the next row for the destination worksheet
- The next section after `insert_index` is where all of the data is copied over. Adjust as needed for columns
- The last item is key to add something back to the original `Copied` column to indicate the copy worked.
- Also note that I never use a `Select` command but rather refer to items directly by their row and column. This is a much more robust method.

Comment: Actually it's a little different.. Initially there has to be just 2 sheets: Master and Data. Master only has one column saying Job Titles. Data has all the information of all employees. I tried to tweak my existing code a little, please see updated code above

Comment: @HomerL Updated mine to have employee data in a different worksheet. Still similar method

Comment: sorry I'm not sure how to apply the second part to what I need.. The Master Sheet only has 1 column: "Job TItle". The Data Sheet has 4 columns: full name, date of hire, their job title, and contact number.

Comment: @HomerL Then pivot off of `Job Title` instead of `Employee`, making sure `Job Title` also exists in `Data`. The method is still the same. Try to understand the process I am using before you apply it to your own scenario then adapt that process for what you specifically need